# Login Users action in, $action_links, how do i edit it?

Tags: theming, navigation, routes

I am still very new to drupal and have let to use all the hooks and coding needed to do everything, now I have come up with a problem, which I can not seem to fix either with a module or by looking at code posted online.

I am using the forum core module from drupal 7 to build a forum, within my page.tpl file I have the render($action_links) option printed on each page. This works fine for logged in user. It displays a 'add new forum topic' as a link. However when a non-user views the forums, its displays 'Log in to post new content in the forum'.

My problem / issue is that only the 'Log in' words are linked to the user login in page and not the whole text. I would like to move the  tag drupal placed after the 'Log in' and move it to the end of the text!

I think I would have to use hook_menu something but I can't really find any information on how to do this for the $action_links. All the hook_menu options I find seem to deal with controlling the main menu output.

Any help give would be most welcome...

Thanks

Glenn Curtis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In D7, if you visit core FORUM module & open forum.module file you will find this code between line no 186 to 208 -

```
if (empty($links)) {
        // Authenticated user does not have access to create new topics.
        if ($user->uid) {
          $links['disallowed'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
            '#link' => array(
              'title' => t('You are not allowed to post new content in the forum.'),
            ),
          );
        }
        // Anonymous user does not have access to create new topics.
        else {
          $links['login'] = array(
            '#theme' => 'menu_local_action',
            '#link' => array(
              'title' => t('<a href="@login">Log in</a> to post new content in the forum.', array(
                '@login' => url('user/login', array('query' => drupal_get_destination())),
              )),
              'localized_options' => array('html' => TRUE),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

This is responsible to generate the link & text which you are talking about. But hacking core is not advisable so please find a way to do it in some other way..

Comment: Many thanks for the help here, I have just parked this issue for now, but will look into how to do it later but many thanks for the pointers given.